# How to fix Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, http-post, postman

I am trying to create a user in postman using the http post request. I used the form-data to input the keys and the values but an error will occur saying SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0. How can I fix it?

```
app.post('/signup', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
    User.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        address: req.body.address,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        contact: req.body.contact,
        event: req.body.event,
        price: req.body.price,
        packages: req.body.packages,
        img: req.body.filename
    }, function (err, User) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            var token = jwt.sign({ id: User._id }, config.secret, { expiresIn: 86400 });
            res.send({ auth: true, token: token });
        }
    });
});
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: @ PrincessJoy Duran Can you post your `signup` code??

Comment: app.post('/signup', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
  User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    contact: req.body.contact,
    event: req.body.event,
    price: req.body.price,
    packages: req.body.packages,
    img: req.body.filename
  },
  function (err, User) {
    if (err) {
     res.send(err)
    }else{
    var token = jwt.sign({ id: User._id }, config.secret, {
      expiresIn: 86400
    });
      res.send({ auth: true, token: token });
  }
  }); 
});

Comment: You must in the "Body" menu select the "raw" format and choose JSON and write your JSON request body as JSON format.

Comment: I did @RaminRezazadeh. But still the same error. I also tried the form-data but still the same error will occur.

Answer (score -1):

You must in the "Body" menu select the "raw" format and choose JSON and write your JSON request body as JSON format. Like the below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I just tried to re-open my postman and rewrite my code.

```
app.post('/account', upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
  let data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    address: req.body.address,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    contact: req.body.contact,
    event: req.body.event,
    price: req.body.price,
    packages: req.body.packages,
    img: req.file.filename
  }
  let user = new User(data);
  user.save()
    .then((doc) => {
      var token = jwt.sign({ id: doc.email}, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
      });
      res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
      res.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send("There was a problem registering the user.")
    })
});
```

It works now! Thank you for your responses.